# Adapter error on a ListView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter, android-context

I want to add a new layout with some specific data to a ListView.
I made a class which extendeds a BaseAdapter, but when I try to put my data and Context (this) in my new class, it shows an error

```
package com.bignner.hotel;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context context;
private ListView Placename;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Placename =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

            RadioGroup RG=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogrop);
            int SelectedId= RG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton RB= (RadioButton)findViewById(SelectedId);
            String textRB=RB.getText().toString();
            int place=0;

            switch (textRB){
                case "Gust-house":
                    place=R.drawable.g;
                    break;
                case "Apartment":
                    place=R.drawable.a;
                    break;
                case "Hotel":
                    place=R.drawable.h;
                    break;
            }
            TextView placeName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            String name=placeName.getText().toString();
            TextView placeAddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
            String address=placeAddress.getText().toString();

            List<HotelEntry> tourPlace = new ArrayList<HotelEntry>();
            tourPlace.add(new HotelEntry(name,place));
            Myadapter adapter = new Myadapter(this,tourPlace);
            Placename.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });
}
}
```

And my class:

```
public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<HotelEntry> hotels;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return hotels.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return hotels.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,parent,false);
    TextView placeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    placeName.setText(hotels.get(position).getHotelName());
    ImageView LetterIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
    LetterIcon.setImageResource(hotels.get(position).getTypeIcon());
    return convertView;

}
}
```

The error is on this line:

```
Myadapter adapter = new Myadapter(this,tourPlace);
```

I also replaced **MainActivity.this** with **this**, but still I see that error.

I don't know why and how to solve it.
I'd appreciate to get some help.

Error:

[image]

Comment: What kind of error does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't applied constructor of `Myadapter` class. So you need to create it.

```
public Myadapter(Context context, List<HotelEntry> list) { ... }
```

And bring `MainActivity.this` back - without it you are trying to place your `OnClickListener` as constructor parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Put the name of the class before `this`

Answer (score 1):

Move the adapter into `onCreate`. Add to the list and notify the adapter within onClick.

Optionally, also move all `findViewById` into `onCreate` since it is a performance hit to lookup views every time you click a button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<HotelEntry> tourPlace = new ArrayList<HotelEntry>();
    Myadapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // These three lines need to be removed from the onClick
        Placename =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        Myadapter adapter = new Myadapter(this, tourPlace); 
        Planename.setAdapter(adapter);
```